# Релавантность, поиск, массивы, php функция

Tags: php, массивы, search

Имеется массив, который содержит массивы. В php есть функция которая ищет в массивах второго уровня (в массивах, которые содержатся в массиве) значение и возвращает количество вхождений искомого элемента, а также индекс массива первого уровня (который содержит массивы, в которых нужно что-то искать)?

Смотрю на php.net, но еще не заметил.

Comment: Нет таких функций в php. Напишите собственную.

Comment: Да. нет таких. Нужно разработчикам сообщить чтобы они в php 10 включили такую фцнкцию %:)). Напишу свою, примерный алгоритм уже ясен из самого вопроса.